# when adding focus to a textbox then adding a space &nbsp using javascript?

Tags: javascript, focus

```
$("#inputField").focus()
```

when the cursor focuses on the texbox i want to do one space, so it moves to the right a little further!! if you know what i mean thanks

```
function insertParamIntoField(anchor, param, field) {
       var query = anchor.search.substring(1, anchor.search.length).split('&');

       for(var i = 0, kv; i < query.length; i++) {
          kv = query[i].split('=', 2);
          if (kv[0] == param) {
             field.value = kv[1];
             return;
          }
       }
    }


$(function () {
    $("a.reply").click(function (e) {
       console.log("clicked");
       insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("#inputField")[0]);

     $("#inputField").focus()







       e.preventDefault();
       return false; // prevent default action
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an event handler for the `focus` event that sets a space  if the input is empty:

```
$("#inputField").focus(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val(' ');
    }
});
```

Or do you want to add a space every time the box is focused? Then the body of the callback function just needs to be:

```
$(this).val($(this).val() + ' ');
```

**Update:**

Ah I see, well the easiest way would be (forget about attaching an event handler for `focus`):

```
$("a.reply").click(function (e) {
       console.log("clicked");
       insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("#inputField")[0]);

       $("#inputField").val($("#inputField").val() + ' ');

       //...
}
```

But you should make sure that clicking the link twice does not result in adding the name twice!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i want it without the condition!!! because the in my script the focus is set only when the link is clicked

Comment: @getaway: Then let the condition be. You don't have to use the code exactly like posted it ;) But this will overwrite the value of the field. Or you do it like in the second example. But still I don't understand how your code should work exactly. What if the link is clicked twice?

Comment: my code is shown above, what happens is, its exactly like twitter, when someone clicks reply button then the @username is taken to the texbox and after i want a space, so to avoid the user typing @usernamegoing to a party!!! u see the going is attached to the @username, this makes the user @ someone else or someone that dnt exist!! thanks and sorry for taking long

Comment: thanks sorry a bit of a newbie in javascript, but the update still deosnt work!! i was thinking ading space in the html tags

Comment: @getaway: But the name gets already inserted into the text field or did this not work either?

Comment: @felix the name deos get inserted into the text field but with no spaces.

Comment: @felix thanks mate it works your a genius!!! sorry for giving you a headache im such a newbie

Comment: @getaway: You're welcome! No worries, everyone started at some point ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this line:

```
$("#inputField").focus();
```

With this

```
$("#inputField").val(" ").focus();
```

Although you might want to adjust your CSS rather than put a space in the field.

```
input[type=text] {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

UPDATE

I notice in your comments you are putting in the twitter account and want a space after it... here is the solution.

```
$inputField = $("#inputField");

$inputField.val($inputField.val() + " ").focus();
```